# Mongoose connection using top lvl await?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to try to use top lvl await to connect to MongoDB with Mongoose, for example, normally I am doing it like this :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

async function startServer() {
try {
      await mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
}
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("connection ready!");
})
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
})

startServer().then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`app is running on port ${PORT}...`)
    });  
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

it work fine and in the console i can see "the connection ready" message and the app is running at port... etc, however if I try to use ES2022 top lvl await like this :

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

try {
      await mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("connection ready!");
})
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
})
app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`app is running on port ${PORT}...`)
});
```

I can see the app is running at port... but no "connection ready" message, I don't see any error either, so I wonder if i am doing something wrong or I cannot use top lvl await in Mongoose ?

Comment: You're attaching your event listeners __after__ the events fired since you wait for the connection before attaching them.

Comment: Ah ! you mean I need to put the connection event BEFORE the connection... if I use the top lvl await... oh my.. thanks >.>